# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) on and off after server IP change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

From the moment the server of my Rails application was moved from one IP to another (app staying with same domain name), some users started to get Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE) - once or twice a day with different pages. Reloading the page always makes the page load normally.

There is a message in Nginx logs

```
2013/07/08 09:18:11 [error] 1490#0: *626 connect() to
unix:/tmp/unicorn.site.sock failed (111: Connection refused) while
connecting to upstream, client: <client_ip>, server: site.com,
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
"http://unix:/tmp/unicorn.site.sock:/", host: "staging.site.com"
```

but why can the connection be refused? It should be related to Nginx config, but I cannot catch the reason.

Any thoughts are really appreciated!

Comment: Was Nginx reloaded or restarted after the IP change to allow it to re-resolve the hostname etc?

Comment: All the environment was moved to physically other server. So yes, everything was restarted

Comment: I think this problem is for the google crome browser.

Comment: Did you try this link https://github.com/vkholodkov/nginx-eval-module/issues/13 this might be helpful for you.

Comment: tried now, but nothing changed unfortunately. And yes, it appears only in Chrome

Answer (score 3):

Nginx reports error as it is reported by the kernel, so it can't be related to nginx at all. Your unicorn probably is overloaded or segfaulting, you should check `dmesg` first.

Comment: yes, that was a coincidence and I thought it could be related. my dmesg shows `[1723197.895344] init: sites/site-redis-1 main process (11460) terminated with status 1` and much less frequently `[1790569.321221] init: sites/site-worker1-1 main process (9495) terminated with status 143`

Comment: Have you looked at your redis and unicorn logs? You should carefully examine all logs in your system, what happens, and why your sites/site-worker1-1 terminated by SIGTERM periodically.

Answer (score 0):

First I will suggest you to follow these steps

1-Update Google Chrome

2-Clean your cache and browser cookies

- Click Google Chrome Menu on the right corner of browser window
- Select Tools from Menu list
- Select Clear Browsing Data
- You will see a dialogue box, check all boxes
- Select Beginning of Time
- Click Clear Browsing Data button

3-Check internet connection

Let me know if it helps you then i have found a video tutorial that will resolve your problem You are only required to follow the steps mentioned in the tutorial

**error 324 fix**

best of luck

Comment: the problem is that I can affect only the code/configs of my site, and probably my own Google Chrome, but not the browsers of my users. But anyway, tried to clear cache and clear the DNS cache of the computer, did not help. Could you please explain what is the nature of the error? What does happen when it occurs?